# Failed to connect my Unity Games with Google Play Service

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-games

I want to integrate my application with google play service.

I open my application, it shows the "connecting to" google accounts page. But when I specify which user i want and then press ok,then I got message "Player Disconnected". I have checked the package name, I have checked my application id, and I have checked the keystore.

How to solve the problem? Thanks

Comment: It's very hard to tell anything with this amount of information. What plugin do you use? Can we look at the source code?

Comment: A log file of the problem would also help find clues about what is going on.

Comment: I'm using "Ultimate Mobile plugin", this is the link of the plugin:

Comment: I'm using "Ultimate Mobile plugin", this is the link of the plugin: [ultimate mobile plugin](http://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/20152 ) . When I import this plugin in an empty project, it worked. But when I import this plugin to my game project, it didn't work. I have tried using the latest update plugin, but when I connect to google acount the result is "Internal Error" .